# NotNavigableException cause

Tags: hibernate-mapping

Whenever I am running my hibernate connection java code then i am getting this exception org.hibernate.metamodel.NotNavigableException: com.javaa2z.hibernate.Customer is not a navigable (managed-type or collection)

I have written hibernate.cfg.xml code and Customer.hbm.xml.
I am using Mysql8.0

org.hibernate.metamodel.NotNavigableException: com.javaa2z.hibernate.Customer is not a navigable (managed-type or collection)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.spi.AbstractRuntimeModel.getEntityDescriptor(AbstractRuntimeModel.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityDescriptor(SessionImpl.java:1492)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:30)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at com.javaa2z.hibernate.Lab1A.main(Lab1A.java:14)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue because haven't set model package in datasource :

```
@Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        System.out.println("Creating entity Manager");
        logger.info("DATASOURCE :"+dataSource());
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean=new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"You model package will set here"});
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(additionalProperties());
        return factoryBean;
    }
```